# AS3: On scroll tween alpha to last children inside scrollPane with dynamic content

Tags: actionscript-3, math, components

I am trying to change the alpha of last children inside a scrollPane component to make the overflowed objects dissapear instead of get cutted by the scrollPane. I mean, the closest a child is to the top or the bottom it's alpha is gonna be closer to zero. If its between the margins alpha equal to 1;

I put a "header" and a "footer" with transparent sprites into the scrollPane in order to have blanck space for the alpha effect and had no problem doing it for the top elements, here is the code:

```
function scrollListener(event:ScrollEvent):void {
    var base = 120;//margins height
    var targ = event.currentTarget.getChildAt(3).getChildAt(0);//get container
    var scrollY = event.currentTarget.verticalScrollPosition;//get scroll position
    for (var n1 = 0; n1 < 10; n1++) {// loop for the children
        var curr = targ.getChildByName("boton"+n1);// current children name var
        var curr_disp = curr.y-scrollY;
        curr.alpha = 1;//default alpha
        if(curr_disp < base){//if Y is inferior to margin (var base)
            var alfa = ((curr_disp)/base)/2;
            curr.alpha = alfa;
        }
    }
};

sp.addEventListener(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, scrollListener);
```

I need to do the same in the bottom where if the child is at the bottom border of the scrollPane it's alpha gets equal to 0 and if the child is at the bottom minus 120 (the var 'base') the alpha will be equal to 1. I am really lost and my deadline is over. Hope some one could give me some advice.

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably be a lot easier (and better looking) to just use a mask on the scroll pan using the ALPHA blendMode

Comment: Hi. In fact that's my temporary solution, but I want that the child fades out with a plain alpha based on position instead of a gradient :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same technique changing the alpha for the bottom

You can use the variables and calculate for the how much alpha to be changed for example from 1-10, 10 alpha is to be decrease or increased in the same way.